# Mobile app downloading JSON with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, json, servlets

I've got an iOS and Android app which downloads data from a database using JSON and PHP. Basically its a lot of mysql queries which returns data from my MySQL database. When I started this project is just created an array in php which holds all queries. Then I would send an index in my url to access that query and optionally some variables.

```
http://url.nl/script.php?index=1&var1=foo&var2bar
```

This worked fine and for a small project it wasn't bad but I knew this isn't good programming nor a good model.

So basically it's something like this:

- APP with Model-View-Controller-Store model
- When app needs data, Store classes request data through url and also send an index in that url
- PHP script reads index, executes saved query in array, encodes data to JSON, returns data
- App's store classes read and decode data
- App's View classes present the data in any way wanted.

So I'm not really doing much with php other than accessing my database, encoding and returning data.

Since my app is getting very large and using more and more queries I wanted to do things right in my new version. What would be a good model for PHP to use in this scenario?

I'm no web developer so I was trying to keep all PHP processes to a minimum but realized this isn't a good way of programming.

Comment: Whether you want to do as you currently are (simply using the web service as an API to fetch & store data, performing all data processing within the apps running on devices) or move some processing into the web service is an architectural choice that will depend upon the requirements of your application... it's impossible to say how much processing should be done where without knowing what your application is doing.  In general, you're probably trying to find a balance that minimises device-side resource consumption (processing, memory usage and network activity).

Comment: Right that sounds logical. I was just hoping that there was some kind of model or example for just this kind of thing. Storing queries and accessing them in an app using an URL. What I'm doing right now just doesn't seem like good programming but then again, I'm no web dev.

Comment: Look up [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). An example in PHP could be [this](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/).

Comment: @redreggae: Whilst I'm all for using a RESTful API, I don't think it helps to answer the OP's question re division of processing between web service and device.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just storing your queries in an array, you should instead use some kind of RESTful API on your server.
You then would send GET requests to your server, which executes them and returns the desired data. This could then be read and decoded. (You can also send and update data to the server).

There are a bunch of REST Framworks for PHP, but i used "Slim Framework" because its really easy to understand (even for people not familiar with php).

This Example from their Website:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();
```

makes it possible to call www.yourside.com/hello/Mark, which then returns "Hello Mark". With 5 lines of code. Its awesome.

You can write any php code there. To encode your data from a MySQL Database just follow this Tutorial: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/ Just ignore the JQuery part.

In your App you then request the Data from the provided URL. I use AFNetworking for this. (Google it, on their page find "HTTP Request Operation Manager" and look at GET)